# SSRS conditional formatting expression

Tags: reporting-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgg8B.png)I have a parameter in my report that populates attributes collectively or individually. ("Fee Spread Method", "Months").
Within my report, there are a series of month columns (Full Date), that display the attribute, based on the value selected in the parameter.

What I'm trying to do is highlight the cell red, if the value changes from the previous month.

Comment: How is your dataset?

Comment: I have numerous fields in my dataset, but the report layout displays customer name, along with the full date (1 field for each month), horizontally. If the value changes from the previous month, for any 1 customer, I want to be able to highlight the cell red. Is this enough info?

Comment: What is the field you want to check if changes based on previous month?

Comment: It depends on what parameter is selected (Fee Spread Method or Months). If Fee Spread Method is selected from the @attribute parameter, then display all records and highlight any cells red, where the value has changed from the previous month. Same logic is used for "Months".

Comment: I would make this calculation in the Stored Procedure and return a flag "IsChanged" or something, then make your formatting expression based on that value.

Comment: I've tried setting an expression for the background colour: =IIF(Fields!FeeSpreadMethodName.Value = "Straightline", "Red", "No Color"). I need to do the same for the field value "Months". I am pretty sure that this is not correct, as there is no pointer to the @attribute parameter. I am struggling because of the display of the report. As opposed to searching for values in any one field (top to bottom), I am needing to look for values, for each month. (Each month has its own field).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Matt. I will look at this, however I think a solution can be done within an expression.

Comment: @Benchenko, Include an example of what you want, try add an image of your desired table you can do it in Excel or any spreadsheet software.

Comment: @Benchenko, does your dataset return Jan-14,Feb-14... Columns?

Comment: The dataset returns full date. I have added a column group, which groups on FullDate. When the report is ran, all fields are shown for the respective months. You almost had the correct output @alejandro, but the FSMethod values ("MethodOne", "Methodtwo") need to be displayed horizontally, for each respective month.

Comment: @Benchenko, check my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this expression for the cell background:

```
=Iif(Fields!FSMethod.Value<>
Lookup(Previous(Fields!Month.Value),Fields!Month.Value,Fields!FSMethod.Value,"DataSet13"),
"Red",
"Transparent"
)
```

**EDIT:** Based on OP feedback.

The above expression will only works if a group is not set. If you have created a group as you expressed it is necessary a different approach since `Previous` function cannot be used in aggregations (groups).

Go to `Report` menu / `Report Properties` and select the `Code` tab. In the textbox put the following code:

```
Dim previous as String = ""
Public Function GetFlag(ByVal current as String) as Integer
    If previous = current or previous = "" Then
       previous = current
        Return 0
    End If  
    previous = current
    Return 1
End Function
```

[image]

Then select the background of the `FSMethod` cell and put this expression:

```
=iif(Code.GetFlag(Fields!FSMethod.Value)
,"Red"
,"Transparent")
```

> The GetFlag function will return `1` if the background color
>   must change.

Using a matrix and arrange the fields like this I recreated your desired table.

[image]

It will preview this:

[image]

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: *Slight amendment* =iif(Code.GetFlag(Parameters!Attribute.Value)
,"Red"
,"No Color")  This worked in the end. Thankyou for your help @alejandro